# 14.04 LTS Ubuntu wifi stops working and disconnects after few minutes from rebooting

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

I installed ( ubuntu 14.4 ) 2 days ago (it's important to mention I'm still a beginner).

On the first day my home WiFi worked fine, but on the second day and until now my WiFi stopped working and if I reboot, it works for about 5 minutes and disconnects again .

Edit 2 : I've run the wireless script AGAIN when the WiFi is NOT working [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9597828/)

and when working [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9597302/)

When running a `tail -f /var/log/{messages,kernel,dmesg,syslog}` in one window and open an additional terminal and doing a `sudo rmmod rtl8723be&&sleep 5&&sudo modprobe rtl8723be` I get the [following output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9554278)

Edit 2 : here's the tail again [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9598000/)

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

As line 2 of your log output:

```
tail -f /var/log/{messages,kernel,dmesg,syslog}
```

contains a

```
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=d8:5d:4c:d5:52:47 reason=3 locally_generated=1
```

and it happens about 5 minutes after log-on, I strongly believe it to be power-savings related.  Therefore type the following command:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
```

to turn off wlan power savings.

Comment: Here you go http://paste.ubuntu.com/9554278/

Comment: Please don't forget to press the little grey check-mark below the 0 to accept my answer!  ;-)
Did this start (it worked for 2 days) after you turned on full power savings?

Comment: When I typed the command in your answer it said command failed: Operation not permitted (-1),

Do I have to sudo this command ?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Updated the answer.  (and don't forget to "accept" the answer!)  ;-)

Comment: unfortunately that didn't solve the problem :( , the Wifi disconnected again

Comment: How long did it hold now?

Comment: for about 10 mins .

Comment: Back to basics:  Post wireless script output before and after it stops working and the tail as well...

Comment: Sorry I've been busy with finals , I've edited the original post with what you requested .

Comment: I've been without a computer.  Please leave me a not after Friday if you want to pursue this... (Sending this from another PC)

Comment: A reminder :D (sorry I forgot )

Comment: As we've deleted our comments previously, and this was a while a go I might have asked this before: 1/ Did you move the computer when this happened?  2/Are you in direct line of sight of the Access point? 3/ Do you have control over the router?  If yes, can you turn of WEP and WPA and only keep WPA2?